# how to get errors from URL.readText() when file not found using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

When I don't have internet on my phone or when the URL does not exist this method not doing anything neither crash nor stop searching. 
I tried this :

```
doAsync{
    val json:String
    json = try {
        URL("http://10.0.2.2:8888/bac/orient.php?ort=1").readText()
    }catch (e: IOException){
        e.printStackTrace()
        ""
    }
    uiThread{toast(json)}
}
```